# Need help with an inner join (self join)

Tags: sql, oracle, inner-join

I have a table with the following schema:

```
Table1
Id       varchar2
name     varchar2
class    varchar2
JoinDate date
size     number
```

The primary key is id, name, class.

When I query for a specific Id,name I want to return sum(size) grouped by class and the results should be based on the following criteria:

1. Only consider rows that have a different Id as me
2. Only consider rows that have the same name as me
3. If a name-class combo for another id matches a name-class combo for my id, then include the size in the sum as long as JoinDate is less than my joinDate for that name-class combo
4. If a name-class combo for another Id does not match a name-class combo for my id, then always include the size in the sum

   ```
   select 
       others.class,
       sum( case when others.class = mine.class and others.joindate <= mine.joindate then size
           when others.class = mine.class and others.joindate > mine.joindate then 0
           else size ) total_size
   from 
       table1 others
   inner join table1 mine
     on mine.name = others.name and
        mine.id != others.id
   where mine.name = :name and
         mine.id = :id
   group by class
   ```

Above is the query I have so far, but it doesn't give me what I want, because it doesn't solve the below case:

```
Id       Name    Class     JoinDate      Size 
OtherId  Mark    Class1    Aug-20-2010   1
OtherId  Mark    Class2    Aug-20-2010   1
OtherId  Mark    Class3    Aug-30-2010   1
MyId     John    Class1    Aug-21-2010   1
MyId     John    Class4    Aug-21-2010   1
MyId     John    Class3    Aug-29-2010   1
```

What I want is:

```
Class1 1
Class2 1
Class3 0
Class4 0
```

That is not what I get.

Comment: That's a terrible primary key :(

Comment: Only problem with his PK is that it isn't the ID column, which is what one would assume. There's nothing wrong with multiple value PKs.

Comment: @Daniel It's a terrible primary key for this design. Why have an ID column which I can only assume is unique and probably auto-incremented and not just use that as the primary key? What is it the other two columns are adding to the key that aide in uniquely identifying each row?

Answer (score 1):

An INNER JOIN ensures at least one relationship exists -- the only way to get zeros is either with a subselect, or a LEFT JOIN.  Try:

```
   SELECT a.class,
          SUM(COALESCE(b.size, 0)) 
     FROM (SELECT DISTINCT t.class
             FROM TABLE1 t) a
LEFT JOIN TABLE1 b ON b.class = a.class
                  AND EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                                FROM TABLE 1 x
                               WHERE x.name = :name
                                 AND x.id = :id
                                 AND x.id != b.id
                                 AND x.name = b.name
                                 AND x.joindate >= b.joindate)
 GROUP BY a.class
```